# A Custom Page for Registered Users showing particular elements to a particular user?

Tags: user

Ok then Joomla Masters, Fasten your seat belts!

It's quite complex but I will try my best to elaborate my goal.

I want to make a **custom page** which will only be accessible to the **Registered users** of my Joomla Website but I want it to **display different elements** to **different users**. Here's an example :

*Supposition* : **Two Registered Users** (`User1` and `User2`)

When `User1` opens the **custom page**, it should display the text `"ABC"`

&

When `User2` opens the **same custom page**, it should display the text `"XYZ"`

But, the catch is **I should able to edit that page for any particular user**. I mean, i should be able to show any **particular user**, the stuff **i want to**.

Is there any body to help me out and push the limitations of Joomla user management to a next level?

Comment: When you say `custom page`, do you mean an external php page that isn't a standard article? And when you say `I should able to edit that page`, do you mean you as an administrator? And edit it how, via the article manager? which leads me back to my first question

Comment: Well, as far as i know, it will require PHP! which my editor doesn't allow to save in an article, so surely i will prefer an EXTERNAL PHP Page. Ya, only i should be able to edit it.
Just like `$user->username` returns the username of the logged in user, i want some kind of script which when detects a specific logged in user should execute a specific code for that user only, is that possible?

Comment: If you want to use PHP within an article, then have a look at this: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

Comment: ok fine, i will do that but i want the code! That's why i posted this question! Remember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want some kind of script which when detects a specific logged in user should execute a specific code for that user only, is that possible?

You can use something like this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if( $user->username == 'Saibbyweb' )
{
     // code for Saibbyweb
}
elseif( $user->username == 'Lodder' ) 
{
    // code for Lodder
}
else 
{
    // else just some standard stuff
}
```

Comment: has anybody told you that you're awesome!
Worked like a charm! Thanks, aton!

Comment: It's been mentioned a few times :P ... you're welcome :)

Comment: It's better if you compare ids and not usernames, since the latter can change.

Comment: @mattosmat - Yes, please write an answer as you make a good point

Answer (score 3):

Lodder's answer is great, but it might be better if you compare ids and not usernames, since the latter can change.

Try this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if( $user->id == 32 ) // Saibbyweb's
{
     // code for Saibbyweb
}
elseif( $user->id == 15 ) // Lodder's id
{
    // code for Lodder
}
else 
{
    // else just some standard stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core profile plugin to do this. Here is a Tutorial for Joomla2.5 to create a plugin to adding custom user profile fields. You can adapt this tutorial for Joomla 3.3.0, too.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/copy-user-profile-plugin